# Find cell before last that is greater than 0

Tags: excel, vba, cell

I have the following code in VBA to find the last cell inside a range that is greater than 0:

```
Set myRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 14), .Cells(1, 23))
count = 0 'Counter
For Each cll In myRange
   If cll.Value > 0 Then
      count = count + 1
      NoZeroDir = cll.Address
   End If
Next
```

It gets the address of the last cell greater than 0 in that range.
But, how could I get the address from the cell greater than 0 before this last one?

I was thinking of using an offset but that way I'd get the cell before the last > 0 but this cell could not be > 0.

To illustrate it a bit, as an **example** I have:

2 3 5 0 1 7 0 8 1 0 1

The address from the last cell > 0 would be (1,11) but I want the cell before that one > 0, that is (1,9), not (1,10) as this is 0.

Comment: What would you do if all values are zero or just the first value for example? Do you assume you would never have edge cases?

Comment: Try `Range(NoZeroDir).Offset(-1, 0)`

Comment: @JvdV yes in this case I know there are no such situations, there's always going to be at least two values greater than 0.

Comment: @FaneDuru how do you mean it? For example if I want after that to ```MsgBox NoZeroDir```, how can I do it?

Comment: `MsgBox Range(NoZeroDir).Offset(-1, 0).Address`.

Comment: @Raúl. *"there's always going to be at least two values greater than 0"*. But what about a zero at only the 1st index?

Comment: @JvdV As I understood, he wants to find the second last cell that is >0. So in your case `0 | 1 | 2` it should return the address of the `1`

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, I understood *"But, how could I get the address from the cell greater than 0 before this last one?"* as though OP is looking for the cell *before* the last found zero. So to it's left. If `A1` would be the only zero. What would the desired result be?

Comment: @JvdV In your cite, the *"last one"* is the last cell >0. So the *"the cell greater than 0 before this last one"* means actually the second last cell >0. He never speaks about the cell that is =0 he always speaks about cells >0. So it is actually about ignoring cells =0 and taking the second last cell.

Comment: Yes @Pᴇʜ , you're right, that was I was looking for. Sorry for late reponse and for any misunderstandings. Thank you all! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the second last number that is `>0`

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub FindSecondLastValueGreaterZero()
    Dim MyRange As Range
    Set MyRange = Range("A1:K1")
    
    Const MAXSKIPS As Long = 1  ' skip 1 number that is >0
    Dim Skips As Long
    
    Dim iCol As Long
    For iCol = MyRange.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1
        If MyRange(1, iCol).Value > 0 And Skips < MAXSKIPS Then
            Skips = Skips + 1
        ElseIf MyRange(1, iCol).Value > 0 Then
            Debug.Print "Found at: " & MyRange(1, iCol).Address
            Exit For
        End If
    Next iCol
End Sub
```

This will start in K loop backwards until it finds a `0` then keeps doing it until skipped `>0` is `1` and print the address `I1` as result.

[image]

Since this loops backwards from right to left it should find the result (in most cases) faster than your code.

Comment: Thank you so much, it's perfect! I changed some parts a little since I'm not looking on the first row but it works perfect! Thank you! :)

Comment: Fyi Posted an alternative based upon MS/Excel 365's `Filter()` function in addition to PEH's valid answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

**Alternative using Worksheetfunction `Filter()` (vs. MS 365)**

Based upon the newer WorksheetFunction `Filter()` *(available since version MS/Excel 365)* and using OP's range indication

```
=FILTER(COLUMN(A1:K1),A1:K1>0)
```

you are able to get an array of column numbers from **cells greater than zero (0)** via an evaluation of the generalized formula pattern.

If you get at least two remaining columns (i.e. an upper boundary `UBound() > 1`) you get the wanted 2nd last column number by `i = cols(UBound(cols) - 1)` and can translate it into an address via `Cells(1, i).Address`.

```
Public Sub SecondLastValGreaterZero()
    'a) construct formula to evaluate
    Const FormulaPattern As String = "=FILTER(COLUMN($),$>0)"
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A1:K1")           ' << change to your needs
    Dim myFormula As String
    myFormula = Replace(FormulaPattern, "$", rng.Address(False, False, external:=True))
    'b) get tabular column numbers via Evaluate
    Dim cols As Variant
    cols = Evaluate(myFormula)
    
    'c) get the 2nd last column number of cell values > 0
    Dim i As Long
    If Not IsError(cols) Then
        If UBound(cols) > 1 Then i = cols(UBound(cols) - 1)
    End If
    
    'd) display result
    If i > 0 Then
        Debug.Print "Found at column #" & i & ": " & Cells(1, i).Address
    Else
        Debug.Print "Invalid column number " & CStr(i)
    End If
End Sub
```

**Example result in VB Editor's immediate window**

```
Found at column #9: $I$1
```

Comment: Thank you, that's also a great solution for my problem. I'll take it into account too :)